# In waterline, how do you group by JSON object?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I want to get a nested JSON object group by clause

```
Collection.find({a: b}).groupBy('c.d').sum('total').exec(function(err, res){
    console.log(res)
})
```

returns
`[{total: 0}]`

if I do the same query except with `groupBy('c')` it returns a result, but I want to group on `c.d`